# Wine Isn't Running Program

Tags: windows, wine

I am attempting to run my Windows video editing software (Corel VideoStudio Ultimate X5) with Wine, however, when I try to run it, it just won't open. I've tried opening it with Configure Wine, the file itself, and through the command line, using the command `wine .wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Corel/Corel\ VideoStudio\ Ultimate\ X5/vstudio.exe`. I have the entire folder with all of the files on my computer, so this should work. Here's the error message I get when trying to run through the command line:

```
fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.VC90.MFC" (9.0.21022.8)
err:module:import_dll Library mfc90.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\sebastian\\.wine\\drive_c\\Program Files (x86)\\Corel\\Corel VideoStudio Ultimate X5\\UiaProvider.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library UiaProvider.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\sebastian\\.wine\\drive_c\\Program Files (x86)\\Corel\\Corel VideoStudio Ultimate X5\\vstudio.exe") not found
err:module:import_dll Library mfc90.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\sebastian\\.wine\\drive_c\\Program Files (x86)\\Corel\\Corel VideoStudio Ultimate X5\\vstudio.exe") not found
err:module:import_dll Library mfc90.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\sebastian\\.wine\\drive_c\\Program Files (x86)\\Corel\\Corel VideoStudio Ultimate X5\\uAfxUnknown.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library uAfxUnknown.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\sebastian\\.wine\\drive_c\\Program Files (x86)\\Corel\\Corel VideoStudio Ultimate X5\\vstudio.exe") not found
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"Z:\\home\\sebastian\\.wine\\drive_c\\Program Files (x86)\\Corel\\Corel VideoStudio Ultimate X5\\vstudio.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[The WineHQ Database](https://appdb.winehq.org/) is where you should check for compatibility before deciding whether or not it's worth the trouble. Anything below gold is a waste of time.

Corel VideoStudio Ultimate X5 isn't even mentioned.

Only a handful of other Corel software and suits of software work.

Bottom line: Don't waste your time trying to make work something that probably never will.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had much luck running anything in wine, and eventually uninstalled it. What you might try is installing virtualization software like `virtualbox-5.1`, and installing Windows as a guest OS in virtualbox. Then install Corel into Windows like a normal install.

In terminal, type:

**sudo apt-get update**

**sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.1**

Then start Virtualbox from the dash, install Windows, then install Virtualbox `guest additions`. After installing Windows, start the Windows virtual machine, and install Corel.

Let me know if that helps. Cheers, Al